# Dialogflow independent input contexts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

In Dialogflow, I have an intent that has two `input contexts`. I want the intent to be triggered when EITHER `context` is present. But currently, the `intent` is only triggered if BOTH the `contexts` are present. What should I do?

Comment: you can define a single context and add that to the output context of all the possible scenarios where you want to trigger the intent ?

Answer (score 3):

I think Biswadip is correct. If you have two output contexts e.g. phone_entered and email_entered that are related to specific intents. Then create a hybrid context phone_or_email_entered and add that as the output context to the aforementioned intents (you do not need to remove the original output contexts i.e. the email_entered or phone_entered ones).

Now you can add the hybrid context as an input context to the intent that you want triggered in the case where either the phone or email has been entered.